# get err timestamp when scan into strct in golang

Tags: mysql, go

what did I do:
1.exec sql query and get err timestamp data when scan to struct after db ddl.
sql:
`SELECT state,round,remark,ctime FROM archive_track WHERE aid=? ORDER BY id DESC`
struct:

```
type Archive struct {
    Timestamp time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
    State int `json:"state"`
    Round int `json:"round"`
    Remark string `json:"remark,omitempty"`
}
```

go code:

```
a:=&Archive{}
 rows.Scan(&a.State, &a.Round, &a.Remark, &a.Timestamp)
```

mysql table info:

```
CREATE TABLE `archive_track` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `aid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `state` tinyint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `round` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `remark` text COMMENT '其他信息',
  `ctime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  `mtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  `attribute` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_aid` (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table data:

| id | aid |state | round  |remark | ctime | mtime | attribute |

|:---|---|---|---| ---| ---|--- | ---:|

| 1  | 1   | 1  | 1| ""  | 2017-03-27 17:07:10 | 2017-03-27 17:07:10 | 0|

I can get correct data first:

`&a{aid:1,state:1,round:1 ,ctime:1490605630}`
but get err data after db ttl(modify state(tinyint) to state(int) ):

`&a{aid:0,state:0,round:0,ctime:-62135596800}.`

db ttl:

`alter table archive_track modify state int`

I can't get correct data anymore until I restart the program.
after I restart ,I can get correct data and err data don't appear anymore ,but why.It make me confuse.

#### Configuration

*Driver version (or git SHA):QD6LqgLz2JMxXqns8TaxtK9AuHs=

*Go version:go1.7.4

*Server version:* E.g. MySQL 5.6,

*Server OS:Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [gomysql](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) as your database driver, then it seems to be that you don't have the [parseTime DSN parameter](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support) enabled for the driver when you connect to your database.

By default, gomysql does not scan the Go type `time.Time` into a struct, but it's implemented as a DSN parameter. Try this connection string:

```
connectionString := fmt.Sprintf(`%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?parseTime=true`,
        DBUsername,
        DBPassword,
        DBHost,
        DBHostPort,
        DBName)
```

Comment: yeah,I'm using go-sql-driver and I had implemented time parameter,I work well, but when I change the database ddl(change state field(smallint) to int ),I can get correct time,but after I restart process, it work well again. It's that any possiblility that changing database ddl affect the  result? I am not sure.

Comment: It could be. When you restart the process, are you also dropping and re-creating the original table definition with the `tinyint` type again? Another possibility is that the `tinyint` type in the gomysql driver doesn't map the MySQL `tinyint` type to an `int` in Go. That would explain why it works when you restart but not when you change the table definition.